# context free grammar example with atmost 3 a's

Tags: computational-science

I have tried a few solutions to the above problem but havig huge doubts. Can someone please break it down for me step by step on how to reach a solution if I want to define a CFG with atmost 3 a's (over alphabets a,b)?

I thought of:

- S -> BABABAB
- A -> a
- A -> b
- A -> e (blank)
- B -> bB
- B -> b
- B -> e (blank)

( I have a feeling it is not right)

Answer (score 2):

This is correct, but can be simplified. As this language is regular you can write it as the regular expressions $$b^*(a|\epsilon)b^*(a|\epsilon)b^*(a|\epsilon)b^*$$

Now we can turn this regular language into a CFG part by part. The overall structure is
$$ S \rightarrow BABABAB$$
Now $b^*$ is expressed by
$$ B \rightarrow bB\ |\ \epsilon$$
Notice that you don't need the rule $B \rightarrow b$ as we can reduce $B \rightarrow bB \rightarrow b\epsilon = b$.

$(a|e)$ is simply expressed by
$$ A \rightarrow a \ |\ \epsilon $$

However your grammar is still correct, as $b^*(b|\epsilon) \equiv b^*$, so adding $A \rightarrow b$, gives you the same language.